# Различное поведение webpack на различных машинах - добавление лишней папки обертки

Tags: typescript, webpack

Я разрабатываю библиотеку, которая будет использоваться в других проектах. Для локальной разработки хочется билдить и использовать в других проектах через npm/yarn link. Она билдится вебапаком, но оказалось, что его поведение может быть различным на разных машинах.

Для начала упрощенная структура папок в библиотеке:

```
lib/
  dist/
  src/
    folder1/
    folder2/
    index.ts
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  webpack.config.js
```

На моей машине работает правильно - команда `webpack` билдит код в папку `dist/` и `dist/`  содержит `folder1/`, `folder2/`, `index.js`, `index.d.ts`, `index.d.ts.map`:

```
dist/
  folder1/
  folder2/
  index.js
  index.d.ts
  index.d.ts.map
```

Но на машине моего коллеги `webpack` оборачивает все в дополнительную папку `src` и оно выглядит так:

```
dist/
  src/
    folder1/
    folder2/
    index.d.ts
    index.d.ts.map
  index.js
```

Мне нужно первое поведение, потому что сторонние библиотеки не находят файл index.d.ts и кидают ошибки об этом. **Что нужно изменить, что получать везде одинаковые результат билда?**

Ниже представлены конфигурации файлов `webpack.config.js`, `tsconfig.json` и `package.json`.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const EsmWebpackPlugin = require('@purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    configFile: 'tsconfig.json'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
        alias: { react: require.resolve("react") }
    },
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'LIB',
        libraryTarget: 'var'
    },
    plugins: [new EsmWebpackPlugin({moduleExternals: true})],
    externals: ['react', 'react-dom']
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "**/__tests__/*"
  ]
}
```

package.json (partially)

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: проверьте версии всего

Comment: у webpack, webpack-cli, typescript полностью совпадают

Comment: "Я разрабатываю библиотеку" - шарят  либо сорцы либо скомпилинованное. https://github.com/developit/microbundle - тебе в помощь.

Comment: вопрос не в этом. она нормально шарится. тут вопрос про локальную разработку, чтоб потом через npm/yarn link ее использовать

Comment: т.е. ты создаёшь папку с проектом, настраиваешь, пушиш в гитхаб потом клонируешь на другой машине с такой же ОС и получаешь разный вывод при компиляции? или всё же разный вывод после npm link ?

Comment: все так. разный вывод при компиляции, из-за которого index.d.ts помещается в не то место, что указано в package.json/types, и поэтому прилинкованную библиотеку не получается использовать